# How to get the content of ComboBox.SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, string, combobox, uwp, uwp-xaml

I thought `ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()` would work, but it's always returning this string: `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem`, while the selected item's content is different.

Comment: You should check for SelectedItem.Value or SelectedValue of the combobox.

Comment: For simple text from ComboBox use `(comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a simple one. 
What you're looking for is the `dataContext` of the `ComboboxItem`'s Selected item. To get this,

1. Create a `SelectionChanged` event for the Combobox.
2. Now that you have the event it'll be providing two method parameters (`object sender` and  `EventArgs e`).
3. Cast the `sender` to a combobox (`var container = sender as ComboBox`).
4. Now, Pull out the selected item as a `comboboxItem` (`var selected = container.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem`).
5. Now pull out the DataContext from the selectedItem and Cast it to the type you've provided (a string or some class type that you've provided).

---

```
if (selected != null)
{
    var dataYouNeed = selected.DataContext as TypeYouDefined; //(string or a class)
    if (dataYouNeed != null)
    {
        //Do your stuff here 
    }
}
```

---

if you do have an access to the combobox directly, then you don't need the event. 
Simply follow the below Code.

```
 var selected = MyComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if(selected!=null)
        {
            var dataYouNeed = selected.DataContext as TypeOfDataYouDifined; //string or some Class
            if(dataYouNeed!=null)
            {
                //do your stuff here...
            }
        }
```